# Make a RESTful API call that updates many related entities

Tags: rest, restful-url

We have a model that looks like this

```
Login <- Email Addresses <- Person -> Teen
```

And a stored procedure which takes some properties from teen, some from person, and some from Login, and creates a new teen, returning a person entity.

Looking from a classic RPC perspective, this is easy...just expose a method `InsertTeen` and have it call the stored procedure.

I've been trying to wrap my head around the RESTful idea of having URLs as my resources (nouns), and the only actions being HTTP actions (verbs). Obviously, a URL like `/api/InsertTeen` is not RESTful at all.

But here I'm not dealing with any particular resource.

The only thing I can thing of here would be to expose a resource like `insertTeenRequest`.

Are there any other ideas of how to do this? Am I being too much of a "zealot"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty new to REST myself, but my thinking is that here you would use a "POST" with the body of the request containing the data needed to create a 'Teen', in whatever format you are using, usually JSON or XML.  Here, I'm not sure whether you treat Teens as Persons with additional properties, or a Teen is modeled as an entity itself:

```
<person login="abc" email="abc@foo.com">
   <person-property-1>value1</person-property-1>
   <person-property-2>value2</person-property-2>
   <teen>
      <teen-property-1>value3</teen-property-1>
      <teen-property-2>value4</teen-property-2>
   </teen>
</person>
```

or

```
<teen login="abc" email="abc@foo.com">
   <person-property-1>value1</person-property-1>
   <person-property-2>value2</person-property-2>
   <teen-property-1>value3</teen-property-1>
   <teen-property-2>value4</teen-property-2>
</teen>
```

Regarding the URI, I believe the segments should be nouns rather than verbs since the URI is supposed to address a resource, so `/api/teens` rather than `/api/InsertTeen`.

`/api/teens` with an HTTP GET would return a list of all Teens, and `/api/teens` with an HTTP POST would insert a new Teen.  To round out the CRUD operations, `/api/teens/{id}` using HTTP GET would return a specific Teen, `/api/teens/{id}` with an HTTP PUT would update a Teen using the values passed in the request body, and `/api/teens/{id}` called with HTTP DELETE would delete the specified Teen.

**Edit**

Read over your question again, and I may have misunderstood.  If you aren't treating 'teens' as a resource, but only 'people', then I would consider `/api/people` with an HTTP POST, and depending on the values passed in the body of the request, do whatever is appropriate to store that 'person'.  So, if the request contained 'teen' values, call your stored procedure that creates a 'Teen' and returns a 'Person'.

HTH

Comment: The thing is, we're not just creating a teen entity, we're also creating a person, emailaddress and login entity, so it feels a bit misleading...

Comment: @blockhead, was editing when you commented.  Not sure if my edit addresses your comment, but perhaps if it feels like it will be confusing to the users of the api, then you should consider treating teens as a resource, using `/api/people/teens`?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be really RESTful, you should use several requests to your API in this case. For example first you create `Teen` with POST to /api/teens/, then create `Person` with POST to /api/persons/ and so on.

Comment: Upon creation of the first resource, the server is completely within its right to create a second resource.  There is no need to expose that to the client.

Comment: Unraveling an encapsulating and atomic operation for the sake of being RESTful, doesn't seem like such a good trade off.

@Darrel I hear that, but for some reason it seems wrong, or maybe I'll just have to chew on it for a few hours